# heroku error TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: html, socket.io

I'm trying to connect my code to heroku, but I keep getting an error. help me

```
2020-04-07T20:49:48.451221+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting     
2020-04-07T20:49:53.948080+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed     
2020-04-07T20:49:53.661562+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-07T20:49:53.661583+00:00 app[web.1]: > heroku_study@1.0.0 start /app
2020-04-07T20:49:53.661583+00:00 app[web.1]: > node server.js
2020-04-07T20:49:53.661584+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-07T20:49:53.848703+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/socket.io/lib/store.js:35   
2020-04-07T20:49:53.848705+00:00 app[web.1]: Store.prototype.__proto__ = EventEmitter.prototype;
2020-04-07T20:49:53.848705+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2020-04-07T20:49:53.848706+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-07T20:49:53.848706+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
```